# Display 2D Arrays in a UITableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a two-dimensional array of temperatures that I would like to display in a tableView.  I have tried to set up this tableView with one section per row of my array, and in each section, one column of my array per tableView row; i.e., what I want is:

Row 0  Column 0 Temperature 0,0
       Column 1 Temperature 0,1
       Column 2 Temperature 0,2
        etc.                etc.

Row 1  Column 0 Temperature 1,0
       Column 1 Temperature 1,1
       Column 2 Temperature 1,2
        etc.                etc.

Row 2  Column 0 Temperature 2,0
       Column 1 Temperature 2,1
       Column 2 Temperature 2,2
         etc.               etc.

What I get is:

Row 0  Column 0 Temperature 0,0
       Column 1 Temperature 0,1
       Column 2 Temperature 0,2
        etc.                etc.

Row 1  Column 0 Temperature 0,0
       Column 1 Temperature 0,1
       Column 2 Temperature 0,2
        etc.                etc.

Row 2  Column 0 Temperature 0,0
       Column 1 Temperature 0,1
       Column 2 Temperature 0,2
         etc.               etc.

All the rows ( “sections” in my tableView) are the same as section zero.

The relevant code is:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        for _ in 0..<numberOfRows {
            areas.append(columns)
        for _ in 0..<numberOfColumns {
              columns.append(eachArea)
         }

        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self

        for var i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++ {    
            for  j in 0..<numberOfColumns {
                let yy = Double(round(100 * temperatures[i][j]) / 100)
                //print("At i = \(i), j = \(j), temperature = \(yy)")
                profileArray.append(["Column" : "\(j)", "Temperature" : "\(yy)"])
            }
        } 
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //Mark: UITableViewDataSource

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return numberOfRows
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (numberOfColumns)
     }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->   UITableViewCell {
        let profileDict:Dictionary = profileArray[indexPath.row]
        let cell: ProfileCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as! ProfileCell
        cell.columnLabel.text = profileDict["Column"]
        cell.temperatureLabel.text = profileDict["Temperature"]
    return cell
    }

    //Mark: UITableViewDelegate

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40.0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "Row \(section)      Column                Temperature"
    }
```

Note that, at the end of the calculations, a print() statement prints the correct temperature values to the console for each row and column.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment to get clarification on your question at a starting level reputation I'll just attempt to answer based on my understanding of your question and hope to somehow earn reputation so that I can ask for clarification before attempting an answer in the future. :)

Answer attempt:
In your `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` method return `cell.columnLabel.text` and `cell.temperatureLabel.text` conditionally based on correlating `inedexPath.section` and `indexPath.row` with your two demensional array where "section" is your first dimension and "row" is your index in the second dimension.

I'd be happy to write up a sample for you if you don't mind providing an example of your 2D array. Again, I would have commented or messaged your personally for further detail if either of those things were possible. Just trying to help :)

Comment: Actually if you were to add some prototype cells on your storyboard and manually enter what you'd like it to render as, attach a screenshot of that to your OP, and give an example of your 2D array that would help us help you! :)